# MEGA download not working with Iceweasel on Linux?

Tags: linux, mega

So I tried downloading a file to my computer from a Mega link and the app loads a screen with a progress bar. The bar reaches 100% but then nothing happens. Does anyone know where my file is? I tried with the command find / | grep "name of file" but it didn't find anything...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have Debian.
Well, Iceweasel is a lot behind the official Firefox, and this can cause problems to Mega.

If you have Debian 7.0 (Wheezy), the latest available Iceweasel is Firefox 20, five releases behind.

If you have Debian 6.0 (Squeeze), the latest Iceweasel is Firefox 3.5 - we're talking about *ages* ago.

Try to install the [official Firefox extension](https://mega.co.nz/mega.xpi) (see the [description page](https://mega.co.nz/#firefox))

Comment: I tried the extension but i didn't work either... I guess I need a newer browser. Thanks anyways!